# Mass build and save of docker images

Tags: bash

I would welcome feedback about this script to automate the building of docker images from a set of dockerfiles.

The dockerfiles are provided to the script via stdin.  The images are saved to the first (and only) argument of this script.  In normal use either one or two specific images are removed manually from the machine so that they get rebuilt or all images are removed (using a different script) for them all to be rebuilt.

Example invocation:

```
$ find dockerfiles -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | dockerfiles-build images
```

Actual output:

```
Reading dockerfile directories from std input.  Building can take a long time...
Building golang-build:2017-03-05T22-28GMT from dockerfiles/golang-build
Sending build context to Docker daemon 4.608 kB
<Lots of docker build process text>
Successfully built cc287d22a661
Saving golang-build:2017-03-05T22-28GMT.save.xz from cc287d22a661
Use images/run-golang-build to use the image
Reading next dockerfile...
$
```

My code (MIT license):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script to build and save specific docker containers to the specified directory with the paths to the dockerfile directory arriving on the standard input

set -eu -o pipefail

if [ -z "${1-}" ] || ! [ -d "${1-}" ]; then
    echo "Correct invocation is: $(basename "$0") _out-directory_ <_dockerfile-directory-paths_" >&2
    exit 1
fi

outdir="${1-out}"
timestamp=$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M%Z')

echo "Reading dockerfile directories from std input.  Building can take a long time..." >&2

while read dockerfilepath; do
    # Filter out empty input
    if [ -n "$dockerfilepath" ]; then

        # Process the path name
        name="$(basename $(readlink -f "$dockerfilepath"))"

        # Check that image does not already exist
        if ! docker images | grep "$name"; then

            # Get docker to build the image
            echo "Building $name:$timestamp from $dockerfilepath" >&2
            docker build -t "$name":$timestamp "$dockerfilepath"

            # Output the image (but only one if there are duplicates with different tags)
            image="$(docker images | grep "$name" | awk '{print $3}' | sort -u)"
            if [ "$(echo "$image" | wc -w)" -ne "1" ]; then
                echo "Multiple images detected for $name; aborting" >&2
                exit 1
            fi
            echo "Saving $name:$timestamp.save.xz from $image" >&2
            docker save "$image" | xz -z9 > "$outdir/$name:$timestamp.save.xz"

            # output the image specific run script, enforcing a naming convention
            cp "$dockerfilepath"/run* "$outdir/run-$name"
            echo "Use $outdir/run-$name to use the image" >&2
        else
            echo "A $name image already exists; remove it to build it again" >&2
        fi
    else
        echo "Skipping empty path" >&2
    fi
    echo "Reading next dockerfile..." >&2
done
```

Points of particular interest:

- Are there any unsafe filepath manipulations
- Are variables treated safely
- Could any names break the script
- Anything that could lead to the script being unreliable for unsupervised operation
- Any general optimisations that you could suggest

Comment: Does the correctness of the script depend on `set -o pipefail`? That seems to be the only bashism that you're using. Also, how concerned are you about portability (e.g. `readlink -f` is a GNU extension).

Comment: While my production environment is bash, I'm not against portability.  Others may be very interested in portability so include whatever suggestions you wish in your excellent review.

Comment: Note that all content you post on Stack Exchange sites is automatically licensed under CC, regardless of the MIT notice you included in there. For more details see the links in the footer of every page

Comment: I hadn't actually noticed that; it's in really small and faint text.  In this case people can use the code under either license.

Comment: Please use the improved code by Gregory below (cc-by-sa 3.0 license) or the maintained up-to-date version https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RidiculousRichard/bash-dev-scripts/master/dockerfiles-build  (MIT license) rather than the original here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good shell script. You're checking for the existence of directories and files before taking any action and using `set -eu` and `set -o pipefail`.

In no particular order, here's what comes to mind.

1) In my opinion, the logic is getting slightly too complex for a shell script. I think you'd be better off in the long run with Python / Perl / Ruby.

2) reading from stdin and processing input from stdin in a loop.

See Stéphane Chazelas' answer to this question.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

If you're going to do it anyway, you should probably to use `IFS= read -r dockerfilepath`.

3) `name="$(basename $(readlink -f "$dockerfilepath"))"` should have quotations around `$(readlink ...)`, i.e.

`name="$(basename "$(readlink -f "$dockerfilepath")")"`.

I don't think quotes around the whole expression are necessary in this case, but it's probably better to keep them there for peace of mind.

also `readlink -f` is not portable.

I'm also not sure why you're using it. Are you expecting lots of symlinks in your environment?

4) `! docker images | grep "$name"`

You can use `grep -q -F -- "$name"` if you don't need the output (and just want the exit status) and want to treat `"$name"` as a fixed string.

I think there are a few other places where you're using grep with $name. Always use `-F --` unless you want the regex behavior.

5) `cp "$dockerfilepath"/run* "$outdir/run-$name"`

This is actually fine from a whitespace perspective. (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)

but you may want to set `nullglob` or `failglob` just to be safe.

Also should just check for the existence of the "$outdir/run-$name" directory earlier so that the operation fails before we attempt to build the container.

I'm not sure what it means if the directory doesn't exist, but a simple

`[ -d "$outdir/run-$name" ]` immediately after computing `name` would be useful.

6) At the beginning test for the existence of "$outdir"

outdir is just like `$1` except it hasa default value of `out`. You can move the test for the existence of `${1-}` until after outdir is set.

7) since you're using `sort(1)`, set `LC_ALL=C; export LC_ALL`. Also, set `LC_COLLATE=C; export LC_COLLATE` for good measure.

8) If you aren't going to go the portable route, you can use `[[ .. ]]` instead of `[ .. ]` for tests.

9) use `printf` over `echo`

More explanation here, basically `echo` does weird things with backslashes. This isn't a huge deal since you're only using echo for diagnostic information, except in `$(echo "$images" | wc -w)` which should be changed to `$(printf "%s" "$images" | wc -w)`.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Here's one possible script with the changes incorporated. I changed the logic somewhat so it now says `Reading next dockerfile` at the very beginning and uses `continue` to skip the current iteration rather than having multiple levels of if-else in the main loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script to build and save specific docker containers to the specified directory with the paths to the dockerfile directory arriving on the standard input

set -eu
set -o pipefail

shopt -s failglob

LC_ALL=C; export LC_ALL
LC_COLLATE=C; export LC_COLLATE

outdir="${1-out}"
timestamp=$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M%Z')

if [[ ! -d $outdir ]]; then
    echo "Correct invocation is: $(basename "$0") _out-directory_ <_dockerfile-directory-paths_" >&2
    exit 1    
fi

diag() {
    >&2 printf '%s\n' "$1"
}

diag "Reading dockerfile directories from std input.  Building can take a long time..."

while IFS= read -r dockerfilepath; do

    diag "Reading next dockerfile..."

    # Filter out empty input
    if [[ -z "$dockerfilepath" ]]; then
        diag "skipping empty path"
        continue
    fi

    # Process the path name
    name="$(basename "$(readlink -f "$dockerfilepath")")"
    outpath="$outdir/run-$name"

    # Check that image does not already exist
    if docker images | grep -q -F -- "$name"; then
        diag "A $name image already exists; remove it to build it again"
        continue
    fi

    # create output directory if it doesn't exist
    if [[ ! -d $outpath ]]; then
       mkdir -p "$outpath"
    fi

    # Get docker to build the image
    diag "Building $name:$timestamp from $dockerfilepath"
    docker build -t "$name":"$timestamp" "$dockerfilepath"

    # Output the image (but only one if there are duplicates with different tags)
    image="$(docker images | grep -F -- "$name" | awk '{print $3}' | sort -u)"
    if [[ "$(printf "%s" "$image" | wc -w)" -ne 1 ]]; then
        diag "Multiple images detected for $name; aborting"
        exit 1
    fi
    diag "Saving $name:$timestamp.save.xz from $image"
    docker save "$image" | xz -z9 > "$outdir/$name:$timestamp.save.xz"

    # output the image specific run script, enforcing a naming convention
    cp "$dockerfilepath"/run* "$outpath"
    diag "Use $outpath to use the image"
done
```

Comment: Is there a portable equivalent of readlink -f?

Comment: Is there any way not performing a readlink -f could cause the script to fail?

Comment: I don't think you need `readlink -f`. If you don't have it, the docker containers will just be named after the last component of the non-canonical path to the directory containing the dockerfile.

The most convenient portable-ish equivalent of `readlink -f` I can think of is `perl -MCwd -e 'print Cwd::realpath($ARGV[0])'`. I would only bother with it if you need the script to run without modification on OS X as well and you're using docker machine or something.

Comment: Are you expecting to run this script as root?

Comment: I don't; on Centos7 the user is added to a docker group which allows them to perform docker operations.

Comment: This is a truely superb review, way beyond my widlest expectations; I'm sure your effort will be greatly valued by many.